# "The multi-part identifier 'sysobjects.name'" error while retrieving column names

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have this query that retrieve names off columns :

```
SELECT syscolumns.name  
FROM syscolumns 
WHERE sysobjects.name = 'MNT_SCENARIO_EXERCICE' 
order by syscolumns.colId
```

but it throw this exception :

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The multi-part identifier 'sysobjects.name' could not be bound.

Comment: Could you maybe translate the French into English?

Comment: ok i try to do it !!!

Comment: @jpw: as you have the error message id, you can always look up the locale of your choice in [`sys.messages`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187382.aspx)

Comment: @RemusRusanu Good point, didn't think of that.

Comment: Please note that `syscolumns` and `sysobjects` are old SQL-Server 2000 system tables that are kept as views only for backwards compatibility. You should use new system views that replaced them - `sys.columns` and `sys.objects`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `FROM syscolumns WHERE sysobjects.name`

If you select from `syscolumns` you cannot reference `sysobjects`, can you? What you want is probably this:

```
SELECT sc.name 
FROM sys.syscolumns sc
JOIN sys.sysobjects so ON sc.id = so.id
WHERE so.name = 'MNT_SCENARIO_EXERCICE' 
ORDER BY sc.colId;
```

You can also use [`OBJECT_ID('...')`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190328.aspx) directly to avoid the join:

```
SELECT sc.name 
FROM sys.syscolumns sc
WHERE sc.id = OBJECT_ID('MNT_SCENARIO_EXERCICE')
ORDER BY sc.colId;
```

And yes, all legacy catalog views are required to be scoped by the `sys` schema. While we're at it, why use the legacy catalog view to start with? Why not use the proper catalog views?

```
SELECT sc.name 
FROM sys.columns sc
WHERE sc.object_id = OBJECT_ID('MNT_SCENARIO_EXERCICE')
ORDER BY sc.column_id;
```

Comment: your are awesome Mr Remus !!

Answer (score 2):

The error is that in your `WHERE` condition you are looking in another table, which you have not selected in your `FROM` clause (***sysobjects***)

```
SELECT sc.name
FROM sysobjects so
INNER JOIN syscolumns sc
  ON so.id = sc.id
WHERE so.NAME = 'MNT_SCENARIO_EXERCICE'
```

This is the query that you should use if you want to display all the columns of a table.

Comment: notice that 'MNT_SCENARIO_EXERCICE' is a name of table that is created in database !!!

Comment: Then you probably want the columns that are in table `MNT_SCENARIO_EXERCICE`, right?

Comment: cool Mr Radu, it work, but i want only the name of colums, so i will use your request with "select sc.name" ! Thanks

Comment: @ucef exactly, `SELECT SC.Name`